# jQuery: How many times will .change() be called if I call it on a class of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mental block at the moment and am asking a silly question. Lets say i have this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="x"/>
<input type="text" class="x"/>
<input type="text" class="x"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".x").change(function (e) {
        //functionality
     });

    $(".x").trigger("change");
});
```

How many times will the change event function be triggered? will it be triggered 3 times? one for each input? or only once?

Comment: `$(selector).method()` always runs `each` loop internally over whole collection to apply method for all instances ...with exception of getter use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be called once for each item in the `.x` selector.

---

In jQuery, something like this:

```
$(".x").trigger("change");
```

is implemented internally by getting the entire collection of elements that match the `.x` selector and then calling `.trigger()` for each separate element.  Though there's no way to code it like this, you can think of it logically like this:

```
$(".x").each(function() {
    $(this).trigger("change");
});
```

---

In fact, if you look at the jQuery source code for the `trigger` method, you see this:

```
trigger: function( type, data ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, this );
    });
},
```

So, you can see that it just loops over the jQuery collection triggering the event for each object in the collection.